# How to launch make while appending a list of values to a variable?

Tags: variables, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

In my Makefile I have defined a variable

```
VAR = -Ddef1 -Ddef2 -Ddef3
```

I'd like to launch make like this

```
make VAR+=-Ddef4 -Ddef5
```

But the space messes things up. How can I set VAR to a list of values, like it's possible to do inside the Makefile? Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Makefile:

```
VAR = -Ddef1 -Ddef2 -Ddef3 $(EXTRAVAR)
```

On the command line:

```
make EXTRAVAR="-Ddef4 -Ddef5"
```

As frequently with the shell, tokens with spaces must be quoted. On the command line `make FOO+=` does the same as `make FOO=`. It does not append, it overwrites (in your case). Thus the trick with a second variable `EXTRAVAR`.